# Some question about the canonical injection

Tags: functional-analysis

I am wonder why we say $E$ is subspace of $E^{**}$，do the elements of $E$ really belong to $E^{**}$？
I know the definition of canonical injection $J:E\to E^{**}$，$J$ is linear and $J$ is an isometry.
Another question: if $Y$ belongs to $E^{**}$ and $Y=J(X) $, can we say that $Y$ belongs to $E$?

Comment: I am really sorry to edit on my phone. Could someone help me to solve this question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that $E$ is a normed space and that $E^{**}$ is the second dual of $E$.

If $x \in E$, then define $ \phi_x \in E^{**}$ as follows:

$$\phi_x(f):=f(x)$$

Then we have $||\phi_x||=||x||$. The canonical injection is given by $J(x)= \phi_x.$

In this sense we have that $E$ is a subspace of $E^{**}$.

If $J$ is surjective, the $E$ is called reflexive. Only Banach space can be reflexove (why ?).

Comment: Sorry! May I ask you again that why you say in this "sense" we have that $E$ is a subspace of $E^{**}$. I am confused with this sentence, and I am wonder if it's the reason that the map $J$ between $E$ and $J(E)$ is a isometric, so if $x\in J(E)$, we can get $x\in E$?  Does $x$ really belongs to $J(E)$? Apologize for my stupidity！

Comment: $E^{**}$ is a Banach space, and the isometric map is surjective. So $E^{**}$ is completed, and then $E$ is completed. Right?

Comment: I think I've solved my problem！ Thank you！$E$ may be not as the same as $J(E)$, but in the sense of "isometry", we can say $E$ is the subspace of $E^{**}$.